# Using Redis for Python to process mass data but the Redis server always shut down.

Tags: python, redis

I want to open DB0 on my Redis server, process data in it, and write to DB1. There're about 3 million keys in DB0. To reduce hard disk operation, I use "CONFIG SET save "300 10000"" to make the server write to disk every 5 minutes. This is my code:

```
    import redis

    idLinkoutIds = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=0)
    idLinkinIds = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=1)

    i = 0
    allKeys = idLinkoutIds.keys() # There're 3,228,675 keys.

    for key in allKeys:
        if i % 100000 == 0:
            print str(i / 10000) + ' million ids completet'
        i += 1

        linkOutIds = idLinkoutIds.lrange(key, start=0, end=-1)
        for eachKey in linkOutIds:
            idLinkinIds.lpush(eachKey, key) # Write to DB1
        idLinkoutIds.delete(key) # DB0 is useless, I just need DB1

    idLinkoutIds.save()      
    idLinkinIds.save()

    print 'Done'
```

When 1 million keys are processed, the Redis server just shutdown and I got "ConnectionError: Error 10061 connecting 127.0.0.1:6379". Then I delete idLinkoutIds.delete(key) just for try and the server shutdown again when 0.8 million keys are processed.

I think it's not the reason of hardware cause I'm using a 64 bit OS and 8G RAM. So I'm really confused. The server just shut down. Who can give me a direction.

Comment: Check that the version of Redis you use is 64 bits (even with a 64 bits OS, you can still run 32 bits executables). Paste the result of the INFO command. Check memory consumption of Redis and your Python client (with top). Especially the Python client (which also has to store 3M keys in memory). Use pipelining. Remove the double save commands (which are useless).

Comment: I'm foolish+_+. Redis is 32bit version. Now my program is running. But it really cost memory. For half of my data processed(1.6 million), it cost more than 4GB. Now 1.8 million data completed. I can't open redis-cli although there's 2GB memory left. I delete keys in DB0 in this procedure so dump.rdb file is still 500MB+. Redis cost more and more memory now. Sorry I'm new to Redis.

Comment: It crashes again cause it cost too much memory after 2.5 million processed. Then I want to set max memory and virtual memory but I can't start the server(maybe I should reboot the machine). I think I should divide dump.db into several parts.